# Migrating from PHP to ASP .NET MVC

Tags: php, asp.net, mvc

I plan on migrating a website from PHP to ASP .NET MVC. However, since the website is large and this migration can't be done in a short time I plan to use both MVC and PHP pages together. So the idea is to replace each PHP page or group of pages with an MVC equivalent.

I have to refactor each page and rewrite it overall anyways so I thought I might as well move to the ASP .NET MVC framework for various reasons.

The question is, does anyone know what are some of the problems I will face while doing this?

Here are some I thought of:
- Logins
  - I plan to overcome this with an ajax request to the ASP .NET website on the background and keeping the login information separately for asp .net.
- Sessions
  - I'm not sure how I can share sessions or if I will even need to.

Other than that, I'm not sure if anything else will arise.

Anyone experienced that have a few things to say?

Comment: Yikes, you plan to do this in production? Is there something preventing you from writing it again in ASP .NET and then switching over? Serving both concurrently sounds like a very disaster prone scenario to me.

Comment: This worries me greatly...

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend that you develop the ASP .NET MVP as a sub-service layer to the existing PHP, and then slowly replace all functionality in the ASP. Once that is done you can then build a new top layer in .NET and switch over.

You do this by having the ASP.NET service listen to the localhost on a different port (i.e. 1080). Each time a request comes into the PHP code, you can slowly replace chunks by passing the call to the ASP.NET service as a REST API request.

Over time the majority of the business logic will be moved to the ASP.NET service, and then you can switch over with a new layer that doesn't use the REST API.